# Nginx upstream returning port - How to rewrite $host?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am using Nginx and am using proxy_pass to proxy through to upstream application server. This is working fine, however the server responds with `https://domain.com:81/`

How can I rewrite the host from `https://domain.com:81/` to `https://domain.com/`

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to rewrite the host, you only specify the port in your upstream.

upstream:

```
upstream someproxy { 
    server X.X.X.X:81; 
}
```

server:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com
    ..... //location, proxy_pass, ...
}
```

And it should work as intended.